# Computing medians of columns and storing them in BQ table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table in the form

```
COL_1 | COL_2 | .... | COL_N
------------------------------
1     | 4     | ...  | 5
------------------------------
4     | 8     | ...  | 4
------------------------------
5     | 9     | ...  | 9
------------------------------
```

The goal is to iterate over the N columns and create N additional columns that contain the medians of the N columns (same for all rows). Below is the result

```
COL_1 | COL_2 | .... | COL_N  | MCOL_1 | MCOL_2 | .... | MCOL_N
----------------------------------------------------------------
1     | 4     | ...  | 5      | 4      | 8      | .... | 4
----------------------------------------------------------------
4     | 8     | ...  | 4      | 4      | 8      | .... | 4
----------------------------------------------------------------
5     | 9     | ...  | 9      | 4      | 8      | .... | 4
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

I see a lot of examples iterating over rows but not much on columns. What is a good way to go about it considering the table in Bigquery is quite big, so ideally want to avoid joins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach - works for any number on col_N columns

```
execute immediate (select '''
  select *, ''' || 
    string_agg('percentile_cont(' || col || ', 0.5) over() as m' || col )
  || ''' from `project.dataset.table`
  '''
  from (
    select split(kv, ':')[offset(0)] col
    from (
      select translate(to_json_string(t), '{}"', '') kvs
      from `project.dataset.table` t limit 1
    ), unnest(split(kvs)) kv
  )
)
```

If applied to dummy data as below

[image]

output is

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain the nested from part where you get the columns, since in my table I have some string columns and I wanted to avoid that percentile function to be applied to those columns. Thanks.

Comment: sure. what subquery does is  - it extracts all column names which then used to construct the main query dynamically which then is executed via `execute immediate`. You can run separately subquery to see what  what it returns. You can also run separately what is inside `execute immediately(...)` to see what final query is constructed here. so you will be able to adjust needed part of it as your real use case demands! if you still will have follow up questions - please post new question with all relevant details and I will be happy to help further.